# ScalaZ: what is "type Tagged[T] = {type Tag = T}"?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I started to read scalaz's [source code](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.1.0-M3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala).

```
package object scalaz {
  import Id._

  implicit val idInstance: Traverse1[Id] with Each[Id] with Monad[Id] with Comonad[Id] with Distributive[Id] with Zip[Id] with Unzip[Id] with Align[Id] with Cozip[Id] = Id.id

  type Tagged[T] = {type Tag = T}
  .
  .
  .
```

How should I interpret `type Tagged[T] = {type Tag = T}` ?

What does this mean ?

Where is this Scala syntax described ?

I am totally confused with this.

What does it do ?

Why ?

Could someone give a super simple example that would explain this syntax for "dummies" ?

... and what it is good for ?

Comment: Here's a pretty good explanation of tagged types http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html

Comment: Thank you, that is the only one I found but the problem is that I am too "dummy" even for that, I simply have no idea what `type Tagged[T] = {type Tag = T}` means and how that works. I was hoping that there is a very simple explanation for this simple looking Scala syntax. Where is its meaning defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's scala structural typing, basically it means that type that satisfying Tagged[T] should have declared 'type Tag' inside

```
  type Tagged[T] = {type Tag = T}

  def acceptOnlyTagged[T: ClassTag](tagged: Tagged[T]): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[ClassTag[T]])
  }

  class A {
    type Tag = Int
  }

  class B {
    type Tag = String
  }

  acceptOnlyTagged(new A)
  acceptOnlyTagged(new B)
```

Class A & B doesn't know anything about Tagged but can be viewed as Tagged because they share common structure

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you very much for the clear and to the point explanation !

Comment: I can't find scala specification for structural types, but his article can be useful: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Structural_Typing

Comment: I've looked it up and found one page about it in the book "Scala for the Impatient".